# How can you map through an array and assign each number to a div?

Tags: reactjs

With this code, I'm creating an array of 10x10 with some fields having the number 1 and other ones with a number zero. I want that on each `<div>` click a value of the array is assigned that can either be 1 or 0. Because for creating the `<div>` we are also taking the length of the grid and creating a 10x10 grid. I've tried mapping over the array, but after each click, the whole array  is logged in the console and not only one value assigned to it.

```
import React, {useEffect  ,useState} from 'react'
import Ship from '../components/ShipGenerate.js'
import '../style/style.css'



function Grid(props) {
    const emptyGrid = new Array(10);
    for (let i = 0; i < emptyGrid.length; i += 1) {
        emptyGrid[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);
    }
    const rnd = r => Math.trunc(Math.random() * r);
 // Here I've tried mapping over the array but it returns the whole array
function detectArray() {
grid.map((currentGrid) => {
  console.log(currentGrid)
})
}

    for (let l=0; l<40;l +=1) {
      emptyGrid[rnd(10)][rnd(10)] = 1;
    }



console.log(emptyGrid)
    const [grid, setGrid] = useState(emptyGrid);

    function togglePieceStatus(e) {
      document.getElementById("piece").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.target.className = "boom"
      })
        }



    const box = [];
    console.log(box)
    for (let x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            box.push(
                <div>
                     // here is where I want to assign it a number of the array
                    <div
                    onClick = {() => detectArray()}
                    className="piece"
                    ></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="piece" onClick={togglePieceStatus} className="box">{box}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Grid
```

Comment: What do you consider "a number of the array"? Is that the 1 or 0, or the coordinates of the place in the grid?

Comment: the coordinates

Comment: x and y hold those values, you use them to set the id of the div to match the coordinates, and/or the value between the <div></div> tags

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grid.map((currentGrid)=>(
    console.log(currentGrid);
));
```

**Note:** After my arrow function, I did not use the curly braces, I used bracket instead.

Comment: `console.log()` will return undefined so the returned array will be an array of undefined elements